# when i deploy my rails app on heroku,the step "verifying deploy.." won't stop.And finally failed to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

when i deploy my rails app on heroku,the step "verifying deploy.." won't stop.And finally failed to deploy.
it looks like:
.....

```
Counting objects: 63, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 16.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 63 (delta 2), reused 55 (delta 2)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://ruby.taobao.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://ruby.taobao.org/..
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
.
.
.
.
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_79f9308360752d0592fbc2b468f9b84c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160229-317-1hewtf6.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_79f9308360752d0592fbc2b468f9b84c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_79f9308360752d0592fbc2b468f9b84c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_79f9308360752d0592fbc2b468f9b84c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.5.1
remote: Verifying deploy...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The step "verifying deploy" takes me a long time ,and finally failed.
What should i do?

Comment: Can you please post your gem file content in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### METHOD 1

**Use PSQL in Development, Test & Production ( Recommended Configuration )**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

**OR Simply add the bellow code in your gemfile at the beginning of it.**

```
gem 'pg'
```

**###############################################################################**

### METHOD 2

**Use SQLite in Development, Test & PSQL in Production ( Not Recommended Configuration )**

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** *Don't do it. You are just going to run into problems down the road. Use the same database in production and development.* [For more details see this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21124804/5239247)

I think in your gemfile, you might have specified to use SQLite in production and development environment. That causes problems in Heroku Deployment as Heroku doesn't support to use SQLite in Production. So yo have to modify your gemfile part about your database gems like something below, but still I remind you using different DB in Development and production is not recommended.

```
gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

**edit Gemfile as above**

- remove Gemfile.lock
- run bundle install --without production
- git add .
- git commit -am "updating database configuration"
- git push heroku master

Answer (score 4):

You're using SQLite, as indicated by:

```
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

Heroku doesn't support SQLite, as discussed [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3). The linked article also states:

> It is important that you use the same database in production as in development, so you will need to install the PostgreSQL database locally.

You need to switch to PostgreSQL if you're going to be deploying on Heroku. I would not suggest that you follow the advice from Praveen George. SQLite allows things that PostgreSQL does not. So, in development you may think everything is just fine only to find out it breaks all over the place on Heroku.

Comment: Sure thing. I hope using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production doesn't cause you problems down the road.

Comment: How kind of you .Actually,it's my first time using stackoverflow, you make me fall in love with this site.

Comment: @jvillian : why my method to solve the problem is not advised to follow ? Is there anything that I can improve in my answer ?

Comment: @PraveenGeorge : As I quoted from Heroku, "it is important that you use the same database in production as in development". Your answer **technically** works, but is in direct contradiction to the recommendations of Heroku.

Comment: @jvillian: yes I suggested him to use SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in Production as he was in favour to use SQLite the most.

Comment: @PraveenGeorge - So, you successfully helped someone do exactly the thing that is not recommended.

Comment: Why it is not recommended ? even the great tutorial like railstutorial.org suggests to do the same. So Sir Great @jvillian can you please post an answer to solve his problem in the most recommended way :P

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Deployment Steps

```
heroku login
heroku create

git remote -v

heroku git:remote -a app_name(which u get when u do 3rd step)

git push heroku master
```

Make sure your Gemfile has

```
gem 'pg'
group :production do
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Reset Database

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL

heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed
```

Renaming Heroku Apps

```
heroku apps:rename newname --app oldname
```

If assets not loading run

```
rake assets:precompile
git add
git commit
git push
```